# Visual Studio creates dlls in bin folder

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have a website that i open up in visual studio. When i run it, it produces *.dll, *.pdb,&.dll.config in the bin folder.

This has not happened in past projects so must be a setting or maybe i created an incorrect style project from the beginning. I also have a couple of nuget packages, would this cause it?

How can i fix this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET Framework it compiles into an exe without any dlls. Using .NET Core or newer (.NET 5+) compiles into an exe and dll. Using .NET Core/.NET 5+ you can publish the project with 'Publish as single executable'

Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFtxjTMl5N0&t=270s

https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/single-file/design.md

Comment: Thank you. no exe files in the bin folder. The examples you provided i think are different as they are not asp.net websites but more console or window programs?

Comment: @GazzaT If you’re using ASP.Net Core the publish method should be the same as .Net Core 3.1,.

Comment: My website is an asp.net website based off the .net framework not an asp.net core website

Comment: @GazzaT You can use the [Costura.Fody nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Costura.Fody/) and it will pack your dlls into the executable.